# JavaFX pulling value from nth column of every row in a TableView

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Sorry about the title, I couldn't think of anything better for it.

The following table is what I'm working with currently
[image]

Below is my code for creating the columns and and populating three of the 4 columns automatically from an ObservableList. The 4th column, # ordered, is editable by the user. My goal is to iterate through every row and update the item of that row with the value that the user has entered for it. I have had success iterating through the rows and getting the Item objects from the row but I have not been able to find a proper way to get the order value for that row.

```
TableView tableView = new TableView();
TableColumn itemCodeColumn = new TableColumn("Item Code");
TableColumn itemDescriptionColumn = new TableColumn("Description");
TableColumn numAvailableColumn = new TableColumn("# in Stock");
TableColumn numOrderColumn = new TableColumn("# Ordered");

itemCodeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item,Integer>("itemCode"));
itemDescriptionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item,String>("itemDesc"));
numAvailableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item,Integer>("quantity"));
```

I have been able to access all items found in my tableView using the following

```
for(Object it : tableView.getItems()){
    Item it2 = (Item) it;
}
```

however this only gives me a reference to the object to update the ordered value, I still need a way to pull the actual order number from the table. To do this I used the following piece of code I found online. Note that itemGUIList is an ObservableList that is used to populate the table.

```
for(int c=0;c<itemGUIList.size();c++){
     Object o;
     o = tableView.getColumns().get(c).getCellObservableValue(0).getValue();
}
```

The problem that I ran into here was that the method getCellObservableValue() gave me the error "cannot find symbol". Searching for this did not give me any results and this piece of code seemed to be working for everyone else.

If anyone is able to point out either what I am missing, or if there is better way to solve this problem I would greatly appreciate it. If you need me to post anymore of my code then please let me know and I will. Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Could you show the declaration of itemGUIList and the table population part?

Comment: @bakcsa83

`ObservableList<Item> itemGUIList =FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

and the items are added to the list by the user, I have another interface where the user inputs the information for the item and then I add it to the list via the following

`itemGUIList.add(newItem);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your declaration of the `TableView`, you're using the raw type.

This results in the type of `tableView.getColumns()` being `ObservableList` and therefore the type of `tableView.getColumns().get(c)` being `Object`, which does not contain a `getCellObservableValue` method.

You should add a type parameter to the declaration, even if you're using `?` to fix this issue:

```
TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>();
```

or

```
TableView<?> tableView = new TableView<>();
```

**Note:**

It's preferable not to use the raw type, if possible, since this allows the compiler to do some type checking and also you avoid having to write some casts in your code, e.g.

```
for(Object it : tableView.getItems()) {
    Item it2 = (Item) it;
}
```

could simply be changed to

```
for(Item it2 : tableView.getItems()) {
}
```

---

Actually using the `TableColumn` to retrieve the number of orders shouldn't be necessary though. You could simply retrieve it from the item itself (or the other location where this data is stored), e.g.:

```
Item item = tableView.getItems().get(0);
int ordered = item.getOrdered();
```

Comment: Hi there, so I did what you said with changing tableView to be of type Item and I can finally use getCellObservableValue with the table which is very nice. However I have run into one more issue. As you mentioned I could skip the whole process of getting the 'ordered' value from the table and use item.getOrdered(). However the items have a default value of 0 for their ordered variable. On top of this, the 4th column on the table is not tied to the Item ObservableList and updated from it. Because of this, getCellObservableValue() cannot pull the value from that cell.

Comment: I ran out of characters on the pervious comment. On top of that, if I tie the ordered column to the item observableList, then change that value by editing it, getCellObservableValue() will return 0 every time since every item defaults to 0, even after I edit the value to be any other Integer, it will return only 0. Is there a way I can return either the edited value of the # ordered while having it tied to the ObservableList or not tie it to the list and still get the value that is put in by the user. Thank you very much for the help by the way

Comment: Where do you store the data? What do you use as `cellValueFactory`?